# Controls instead of icon in system tray icon in c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to add control like check-box in system tray icon in c#?
i wants to handle check and uncheck event within that checkbox. So that i dont need to handle it on ContextMenu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can only set the icon and handle clicks, doubleclick, etc...
However, you can simulate the checkbox behaviour by changing the icon.

Comment: And here are corresponding Microsoft Guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#notification

Comment: i have handled it by changing icon but i wants to knew about the controls integration

Comment: The area where is icon displayed is not available for your application. You can not insert any controls there.